# Do we always have an uncountable number of transcendental numbers between any two different real numbers?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

> If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a<b$ is it true that there is an uncountable number of transcendental numbers between $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are.

Any (nonempty) interval $(a, b)$ is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument), and [the union of two countable sets is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780043/prove-that-the-union-of-two-disjoint-countable-sets-is-countable). So all you need now is the fact that the set of *algebraic* numbers is countable. HINT: how many polynomials with rational coefficients are there? (If you want more details [see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489186/prove-that-the-set-of-all-algebraic-numbers-is-countable).)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is true. The set of all algebraic numbers is countable, while the whole interval is uncountable.